# Tooltip and dropdown-toggle are not working with together

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am working on a bootstrap dropdown and tooltip.

The problem is this are not working to gather. When I put the tooltip and dropdown-toggle together in anchor tag then just tooltip is working dropdown-toggle is not working at that time Here is the code which is not working:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Your Application Detail" 
class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" id="candidate_credit_status" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">

    <i class="md md-account-balance-wallet"></i> <span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger"></span>

</a>
```

This is the total code in which i didn't use tooltip, just dropdown-toggle is used. In this dropdown-toggle is working but as previous describe if i put tooptip then only tooltip work.

```
<li class="dropdown top-menu-item-xs app_status">

<a href="#" data-target="#" title="Credit Detail" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" id="application_status" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    <i class="md md-account-balance-wallet"></i> <span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger"></span>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg">
    // Dropdown Detail
</ul>
```

To solve this issue I have tried to use jquery on mouseover. But also not working.

```
$('.app_status').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).attr("data-toggle","tooltip");  
    $(this).attr("data-placement","bottom");
    $(this).attr("data-original-title","Credit Detail");    
    // Also tried this:
    //$('#application_status').tooltip();  but this is not working
});
```

Why this are not working to gather?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap add tooltip to dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423406/bootstrap-add-tooltip-to-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your hyperlink in a div and add tooltip to the div (title is the tooltip), e.g. :

```
<div title="Credit Detail" class="your_tooltip_class" >
    <a href="#" data-target="#" title="Credit Detail" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" id="application_status" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        <i class="md md-account-balance-wallet"></i> <span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```